# Convergence of the series $\sum_1^\infty \tan\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can someone help me understand if this series converges or not?

$$\sum_2^\infty \tan\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2} $$

My attempts:

$\tan(\frac{1}{n})  \sim _\infty  \frac{1}{n} $ and also $\log(\log n)< \log n < n$ for large enough $n$. But, it seems like this doesn't help me at all... I also know that $\tan x<x$ for every $x>0$ , but this also doesn't help me at all.

Will someone please help  me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know for which $p$ the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^p}$$ converges? (Aside, for $n = 1$, your term is not defined.)

Comment: @DanielFischer : Got no idea. I can't solve my question without it ? Thanks !

Comment: You can also compare to the integral $$\int_2^\infty \frac{\log (\log t)}{t(\log t)^2}\,dt,$$ if that is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielFischer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\log(\log(n))=_\infty o(\log^{1/2}(n))$$
and 
$$\tan\left(\frac 1 n\right)\sim\frac 1 n$$
so
 $$\tan\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2} =_\infty o\left(\frac{1}{n\log^{3/2}(n)}\right)$$
now using the integral comparison test we see easily that the series
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log^{3/2}(n)}$$
is convergent hence the given series is convergent.

Comment: Good points are gathered here. :)

Comment: Why is $\log \log (n) = o(\log^{1/2}(n))$?

Answer (score 0):

**Result $\bf1$:**

Since $\tan(x)$ is convex, we have that $\frac{\tan(x)}x=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(0)}{x-0}$ is increasing. Threrefore, $n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)$ is decreasing. Thus, for $n\ge1$,
$$
1\le n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)\le\tan(1)\tag1
$$

---

**Result $\bf2$:**
$$
\begin{align}
\log(x)
&=\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}t\tag{2a}\\
&\le\left(\int_1^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_1^x\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/2}\tag{2b}\\
&\le\left(\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2}\right)^{1/2}\sqrt{x-1}\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&\le\sqrt{x}\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ write $\log(x)$ as an integral
$\text{(2b):}$ [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
$\text{(2c):}$ bound the left integral
$\phantom{\text{(2c):}}$ evaluate the right integral
$\text{(2d):}$ evaluate the left integral
$\phantom{\text{(2d):}}$ $x\le x-1$

---

**Convergence:**

The bounds in $(1)$ imply
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^\infty\tan\left(\frac1n\right)\frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2}
&=\sum_{n=3}^\infty n\tan\left(\frac1n\right)\frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2}\frac1n\tag{3a}\\
&=[1,\tan(1)]_\#\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)^2}\frac1n\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
where $[a,b]_\#$ is some value in $[a,b]$.

The [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) says that $(3)$ converges iff
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n\log(2))}{n^2\log(2)^2}\frac{2^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)}{n^2\log(2)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(\log(2))}{n^2\log(2)^2}\tag4
$$
converges.

By $(2)$, $\log(n)\le\sqrt{n}$, so both sums on the right side of $(4)$ converge. Thus, $(4)$ converges, and therefore, $(3)$ converges. Including the $n=2$ term, does not alter the convergence.